# Is there a way (e.g. parallelizing, multithreading, multiprocessing) to optimize the runtime of for-loop?

Tags: python, pandas, parallel-processing, nlp, spacy

```py
import pandas as pd
import spacy
from spacy.lang.de import German
from collections import defaultdict

data = pd.DataFrame()

#json file 2017
for year in range (2017,2018):
    data = pd.concat([data, pd.read_json("%d.json" % year, orient = "records")], ignore_index=True)

nlp = spacy.load('de', disable=["ner"])

nouns = defaultdict(lambda: 0)
verbs = defaultdict(lambda: 0)
adjectives = defaultdict(lambda: 0)

#for loop that takes an enormous amount of time
for i, row in data.iterrows():
    doc = nlp(row["headline"] + " " + row["text"])

    filteradj = filter(lambda x: x.pos_ == 'ADJ', doc)
    filternoun = filter(lambda x: x.pos_ == 'NOUN', doc)
    filterverb = filter(lambda x: (x.pos_ == 'AUX') | (x.pos_ == 'VERB'), doc)

    punctlen = len(list(map(lambda x: x.text, filter(lambda x: x.pos_ != 'PUNCT', doc))))
    adjlen = len(list(map(lambda x: x.text, filter(lambda x: x.pos_ == 'ADJ', doc)))) 
    nounlen = len(list(map(lambda x: x.text, filter(lambda x: x.pos_ == 'NOUN', doc))))
    verblen = len(list(map(lambda x: x.text, filter(lambda x: (x.pos_ == 'AUX') | (x.pos_ == 'VERB'), doc))))

    data.at[i, "nr_token"] = punctlen
    data.at[i, "nr_adj"] = adjlen
    data.at[i, "nr_noun"] = nounlen
    data.at[i, "nr_verb"] = verblen

    for a in map(lambda x: x.lemma_, filteradj):
        adjectives[a] += 1 

    for n in map(lambda x: x.lemma_, filternoun):
        nouns[n] +=1 

    for v in map(lambda x: x.lemma_, filterverb):
        verbs[v] += 1
```

I would like to do some analyses on different json files.

The basic structure of pandas is the so-called **DataFrame**. I first created a DataFrame and then append the data for the individual years (here only one year) to it. This ensures that the data is all available in the same structure.

The **NLP object** created by **spaCY** is very large and needs a lot of memory. To mitigate this, only the required data is stored, i.e. number of tokens, adjectives, nouns and verbs. Defaultdict helps because all values are set to 0, which saves many case distinctions.

The words themselves are also needed in their **lemmatized form** (i.e. grammatically reduced to the basic form) in order to be able to carry out analyses with them later.

The code is running on a VM in the Google Cloud.
By adding CPU's the runtime of the for loop changes only slightly.

Is there a way to **parallelize the for loop** (e.g. by multithreading, multiprocessing or similar) to reduce the runtime significantly and add more json-files than one?

Comment: Besides parallelizing, but you could surely speed up the inner loops by (1) not calculating the filtered lists twice, and (2) not calling `map` and `list` if you just need the `len`.

Comment: thanks @tobias_k, this nearly halved the runtime.

Comment: BTW; is it intentional that you increase `data.at[i, "nr_adj"]`  (which is independent of `a`, `n`, or `v`) by the `len` of the list _for each element_ of the list? I.e., this is the same as doing `data.at[i, "nr_adj"] = len(...)**2` outside of the loop, which is kind of odd. Should this assignment instead be outside of the inner loops?

Comment: @tobias_k You're right. I placed the assignment outside the inner loop now.

Comment: You are using only POS, hence disable NER when loading spacy model `nlp = spacy.load('de', disable=["ner"])`

Comment: @l.augustyniak The runtime has been reduced by approx. 30% by simply disabling NER. Thank you.

Comment: I know :) You are welcome! There are several performance tips and tricks with spacy. btw `iterrows()` is also quite slow, even comparing to `itertuples()`. You can also parallelize for loop with i.e., `joblib`.

Comment: You can also use `https://spacy.io/api/doc#count_by` to count POS.